# I am having trouble splitting string with a comma

Tags: java

Here is my code and the error that is being thrown:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStrings {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scnr  = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner inSS = null;
        String inputString = "";
        String firstWord = "";
        String secondWord = "";

        inSS = new Scanner(inputString);
        boolean flag = false;
        while (!flag){
            System.out.print("Enter input string: \n");
            inputString = scnr.nextLine();
         if (inputString.equals("q")){
             flag = true;
         break;
         }
            // comma = inputString.indexOf(",");
         if (!inputString.contains(",")){
         System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");
         }
         // if (comma <= 0)
         // {
         // System.out.println("Error: No commas in string.");
         // flag = true;
         // }
         // else
         // {
         else
         {
         for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++){
         firstWord = inSS.next();
         // comma = inSS.next();
         secondWord = inSS.next();
         System.out.println("First word: " + firstWord);
         System.out.println("Second word: " + secondWord);
         // flag = false;
         }


         return;
         }
        }
         }           
}
```

Input
Jill, Allen
q

Your output starts with Enter input string: 
***Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at 
Expected output starts with***
Enter input string: 
First word: Jill
Second word: Allen

Comment: I would recommend learning to use the `split` method of the `String` class.  It makes this kind of operation much simpler.

Comment: it wants me to incorporate "comma = inputString.indexOf(",");" and then when the value of indexOf is "-1" it will return "Error no comma in string: "

Comment: my apologies, it wants me to split first and second word

Comment: OK, but you're making things far too hard for yourself.  As it happens, your `for` loop is repeating everything `inputString.length()` times, where I think you only want to run that loop once.

Comment: here's what I've been able to get points on1. Compare output
1/1
Input
Jill, Allen
q
Your output correctly starts with 
Enter input string: 
2. Compare output
2/2
Input
Jill Allen
JillAllen
Jill  Allen
q
Your output correctly starts with 
Enter input string: 
Error: No comma in string
Enter input string: 
Error: No comma in string
Enter input string: 
Error: No comma in string
Enter input string:

Comment: It does want me to do that but if a user enters a "First word" and "Second word" it wants me to split those words up so it looks like

Comment: Enter input string: 
First word: Jill
Second word: Allen

Comment: where first word and second are input: Jill, Allen

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this task but I want to point you towards the a few common methods from Java's [**String Class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

1. The
   [**String.substring()**](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-substring)
   in combination with the
   [**String.indexOf()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_indexof_string.htm)
   methods can quickly split the string to acquire the data you want
   and it would work something like this:

   ```
   String inputString = "Hello, World";
   String firstWord = inputString.substring(0, inputString.indexOf(","));
   String secondWord = inputString.substring(inputString.indexOf(",") + 2); 
   // Why use the number 2 above? Read the supplied links. Try it with 1
   // to see what happens.
   System.out.println(firstWord + "-" + secondWord);
   ```
2. The other method well worth looking into would be the
   [**String.split()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm)
   method. Use of this method can make quick work of what you're trying
   to do by taking the input string and placing the string components
   that are delimited with a comma (or whatever) into a One Dimensional
   String Array:

   ```
   String inputString = "Hello, World";
   String[] words = inputString.split(", ");
   System.out.println(words[0] + "-" + words[1]);
   ```

Read about these methods.